# Auto showing tips and closing popup when lost focus

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, popup

I have two elements: a `TextBox`, and a `Popup`, where the popup contains a tree view to show some tips according to text of `TextBox`. When the textBox got the `KeyDown` Event, the `KeyDown` directly executes `pup.IsOpen=true` to show the popup tips.

However, I also want to show the popup tips when the mouse on clicking the `TextBox`, and auto closing the popups when the mouse click on any place (besides the `TextBox` and the `TreeView` in Popup).

I have tried some cases but do not works fine.

Case1: Add `pup.IsOpen=true;` in `TextBox.PreviewMouseUp`, the popup will stay opening, even if I click any other place in the window.

Case2: Add `pup.IsOpen=true` in `TextBox.PreviewMouseDown`, the popup tips only shows on keep clicking the Mouse.

Case3: Using `CheckBox` with `Binding IsChecked` to `Popup.IsOpen` works fine. but the tips is listed according to the content of the TextBox, therefore the checkbox is not editable for user...

Here is my code now:

```
<Window x:Class="popUpTesting.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox 
            Name="SearchBox" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            Text="TextBox" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            KeyDown="SearchBox_KeyDown" PreviewMouseUp="SearchBox_PreviewMouseUp"
            />

        <Popup 
            Placement="Bottom" 
            AllowsTransparency="True"  
            PopupAnimation="Fade" 
            StaysOpen="false"
            x:Name="pup" 
            PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=SearchBox}"
            IsOpen="False"
            >
            <Grid>
                <TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="A">
                        <TreeViewItem Header="A1"/>
                    </TreeViewItem>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="B"></TreeViewItem>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="C"></TreeViewItem>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="D"></TreeViewItem>
                </TreeView>
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the event functions:

```
private void SearchBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    pup.IsOpen = true;        
}

private void SearchBox_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    pup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register **`PreviewMouseUp`** event on your window and check if original source is **`SearchBox`** then *set IsOpen to true else set it to false*.

*XAML:*

```
<Window PreviewMouseUp="Window_PreviewMouseUp">
  ...
</Window>
```

*Code behind:*

```
private void Window_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource == SearchBox)
    {
        pup.IsOpen = true;
    }
    else
    {
        pup.IsOpen = false;
    }
}
```